# ionic storage remove function removes data but app size does not change

Tags: ionic-framework, capacitor, ionic-storage

I am using ionic storage (with SQlite) to store images in my app (not the best solution but the images are sensitive and I don't want to store it online). So I am able to store images and everything works fine. But when I delete images, it is deleted from the app but the app size does not change, meaning the data is still stored somewhere. I checked my ICloud to see if the app is synced, but it's not. I am not sure what I need to do because I do not want the app size to increase with unused data

I tried setting "BackupWebStorage" to false but that didn't work either